# Why is my Admin user magically transformed to SHAREPOINT\system?

Tags: administration, user-profile-service, user-accounts

I have an administator, which also is Farm Administrator in my Sharepoint environment. It is synced via UPSA and have all the properties I need do display content the right way. However - when I check the admin user in code behind it gets magically transferred to be SHAREPOINT\system instead of DOMAIN\Administrator... why is that?

Code behind:

```
try
{
    SPWeb currentWeb = SPContext.Current.Web;
    SPUser currentUser = currentWeb.CurrentUser;
    // currentUser is now SHAREPOINT\System
```

The Code behind is in a regular WebControlCode. Regular non-admin users get the correct currentUser attribute.

Comment: where is this code-behind?

Comment: In our own developed sharepoint solution - called MyDepartment.cs. It's there to add a link to "My Department" through a user property: Department - to link correct.

Comment: sorry, what I mean is, when it runs on the server, what is it running as? A regular web part? A sandboxed web part? Part of a timer job?

Comment: I am taking a stab in the dark here but..

I presume it is because the code you are running is in SPSecurity.RunWithElevatedPrivileges?

When running with this, the user becomes SHAREPOINT\System.

Comment: Oh OK :-) It's a regular WebControlCode.

Comment: @HughWood I thought that too, but regular non admin users is handled correct. I'll update my question with this information.

Comment: If you're not using RunWithElevatedPrivileges, does this user have a web application user policy set to "Account operates as System"? While I'm not 100% sure which takes precedence, I'd assume a user policy may supersede the user where system accounts are concerned.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use something like this -

```
private SPUser GetCurrentUser()
{    
    if (SPContext.Current.Web.CurrentUser.LoginName.Equals("SHAREPOINT\\system"))     
        return SPContext.Current.Web.SiteUsers[HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name];     

    return SPContext.Current.Web.CurrentUser;
}
```

and then use it in your code -

```
SPUser currentUser = GetCurrentUser();
```

If you are unsure about SPContext.Current.Web you may pass the SPWeb object as paramater

Hope this helps :)

Comment: if I change CurrentUser.ToString() to CurrentUser.LoginName it works like a charm! Thanx for your answer!